# Find longest substring in two words with suffix tree

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, tree, suffix-tree

I need to solve problem - find longest substring in two words with suffix tree. I built suffix for first and secod word, but how can I find longest substring in two words?
Could you suggest a possible algorithm for solving this problem?

Comment: You mean longest common substring?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use a single suffix tree for both words:

1. First use some non-strings character like `$` or `#` or something (must not be part of any string) to join strings

   *i.e. strings `abra` and `abracadabra` get joined to `abra$abracadabra#`*
2. Then build suffix tree from that.
3. Now from leaves ending with `$` climb up and mark nodes as part of word1
4. Do the same for leaves ending with `#`, marking them as part of word2
5. Now we can do simple `DFS` traversal from root, as longest sub-string will be some path from root (only checking nodes that are part of both words)

Complexity - `O(a+b)` (suffix tree building (if build fast way) + `O(a+b)` (dfs) = `O(a+b)`

Comment: A generalised suffix tree is the way to go, but DFS and skipping paths with the sentinel is not quite enough. You definitely don’t want to search past $ since that won’t be a shared string, but there are other strings that aren’t shared either. If the string is a$bbbb the longest string without $ is bbbb which only occurs once. You only want inner nodes. But there, the longest is bbb. You want inner nodes with leaves from both strings. A DFS identifying which nodes have children in both strings first, and then a DFS identifying repeats will do it, and still in O(a+b)